# How to configure the terminal so that a mouse click will move the cursor to the current mouse position

Tags: mouse, xterm, cursor

What I'm looking for is how to configure the terminal so that it behaves like nano -m.
I know that xterm inside fvwm2 running on slackware does this but neither gnome or kde does it. I have tested installing fvwm2 in Ubuntu but xterm still does not have that feature.

Comment: Why do you think this is useful?

Comment: It makes editing a little easier especially for long lines not separated by spaces where Ctrl-Arrow-Key doesn't help. Pushing the arrow key and waiting for it to get to the spot I want to edit can sometimes take a while.

Comment: It is also useful for anyone who does not know shortcut keys for editing commands in the terminal (I have used Unix terminals for years and had no idea that Ctrl+Arrow would skip between words in some). I think it is generally good for a user interface to support easily-discoverable methods of interacting, and clicking a mouse to move a cursor is probably the easiest method to discover for most users.

Answer (score 7):

You can enable mouse position reporting on an X11 terminal emulator, but you need a co-operating application to read the position and act on it. The terminal doesn't do it on its own. `nano` obviously does it, and so do other screen-oriented applications (e.g. `links`).

If you're just using the command-line, this won't be very useful unless you have a mouse-tracking version of `libreadline`. Even then, I suspect that moving your hand off the keyboard, moving a mouse/using a trackpad, then moving back to the keyboard is slower than <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>.

Here's a [very long list of various terminal directives](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html), including mouse tracking on various terminal emulators.

Comment: I think this answer should be edited to remove the line about using the mouse being slower than using a keyboard shortcut that many users do not know. This sentence does not help answer the question, could distract some readers from the relevant information, and could serve to drive users away from Unix because the community appears to not recognize that not all users know what they know.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo -e "\e[?1000;1006;1015h" # Enable tracking
```

Script : I made a bash script to move bash readline cursor on mouse click on my [github](https://github.com/tinmarino/mouse_xterm/blob/master/mouse.sh)

Details : Read my answer in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55437976/2544873)